# Python - Use json value on BeautifulSoup command

Tags: python, json, parsing, variables, beautifulsoup

im struggling with some Python and JSON stuff right now.

I have a JSON File with some values:

```
{
    "labels":{
        "buybox":{
            "container": "'id' : 'product-top'"
        },
        "instock":{
            "container":  "'div', class_= 'row border-bottom'",
            "text": [
                "auf lager",
                "ware neu eingetroffen"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

After parsing this Json, I would like to use the labels -> buybox -> container value in a BeautifulSoup command like:

`buybox = soup.find(buybox_container)`

But when I trie to write the JSON value into a variable the variable is a string and I think this wont work because the "buybox" variable is empty.

soup.find cant interpret the string from the value "buybox_container" I guess.

Is there a way to get this working?

Comment: Where does BeautifulSoup come into this? Are you dealing with html at some point?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems like your JSON file is encoding function arguments and you want to programmatically use the JSON file to invoke the function in certain ways.

This is mostly a Python question, but if you encoded like this:

```
{
    "labels": {
        "buybox": {
            "container": {
                "kwargs": {
                  "id" : "product-top"
                }
            }
        },
        "instock": {
            "container": {
                "args": [
                    "div"
                ],
                "kwargs": {
                    "class_": "row border-bottom"
                }
            ],
            "text": [
                "auf lager",
                "ware neu eingetroffen"
            ]
        }
    }
}
```

and then invoked like this:

```
buybox_container_params = json.loads(your_data)["labels"]["buybox"]["container"]
buybox = soup.find(*buybox_container_params.get("args", []), **buybox_container_params.get("kwargs", {}))
```

it would correctly interpret the JSON that looks like a list as a list of args, and the JSON that looks like a dict as keyword values.  This relies on some Python features known as "unpacking":

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#expression-lists

https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#dictionary-displays

Comment: Thanks I tried, but getting errors ...
Like `syntaxError: invalid syntax`  on a print(buybox) after the soup.find or if I comment out this line `SyntaxError: unexpected EOF while parsing`

Edit: Found the problem there is a ')' missing.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: ah you are correct, I missed a `)`.  Updated to include it.  Happy scraping.

Answer (score 0):

Just use json library to access container value. bs4 is for parsing html.

```
import json

s = '''{
    "labels":{
        "buybox":{
            "container": "'id' : 'product-top'"
        },
        "instock":{
            "container":  "'div', class_= 'row border-bottom'",
            "text": [
                "auf lager",
                "ware neu eingetroffen"
            ]
        }
    }
}'''
data = json.loads(s)

print(data['labels']['buybox']['container'])
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are trying to access the value of `labels.buybox.container`, an easier way might be:

```py
import json
j = open('test.json', 'r').read()
buybox_container = json.loads(j)['labels']['buybox']['container']
print(buybox_container)
```

Answer (score 0):

is this the result you like?

```py
import json

f = """
{
    "labels":{
        "buybox":{
            "container": "'id' : 'product-top'"
        },
        "instock":{
            "container":  "'div', class_= 'row border-bottom'",
            "text": [
                "auf lager",
                "ware neu eingetroffen"
            ]
        }
    }
}
"""
data = json.loads(f)
print(data.get("labels").get("buybox").get("container"))
```

`Output: 'id' : 'product-top'`